# Generar XML con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Quiero generar un archivo XML por medio de una consulta MySQL a través de PHP.

Tengo este codigo pero no me funciona:

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->setIndentString(' '); 
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$xml->startElement("colegio"); //elemento colegio
   $xml->writeAttribute('Ciudad', 'Valencia');
   $xml->writeAttribute('Municipio', 'Puerto de Sagunto');
   $xml->writeAttribute('Nombre', 'Maestro Tarrazona');

   $xml->startElement("director"); //elemento director
   $xml->writeAttribute('edad', '38');
   $xml->text('Nombre del director');
   $xml->endElement(); //fin director

   $xml->startElement("curso"); //elemento curso
      $xml->writeAttribute('nivel', '4');
      $xml->writeElement("aulas", 3);
      $xml->writeElement("profesores", "4");
      $xml->writeElement("alumnos", "70");
      $xml->writeElement("profesores de refuerzo", 1);
                
      $xml->startElement("profesores"); //elemento profesores
         $xml->writeElement("nombre", "Nombre inventado 1");
         $xml->writeElement("nombre", "Nombre inventado 2");
         $xml->writeElement("nombre", "Nombre inventado 3");
         $xml->writeElement("nombre", "Nombre inventado 4");
      $xml->endElement(); //fin elemento profesores
                
      $xml->startElement("alumnos"); //elemento alumnos
         $xml->startElement("clase"); //elemento responsable
            $xml->writeAttribute('id', "Clase A");
            $xml->startElement("alumno"); //elemento alumno
               $xml->writeAttribute('dni', "xxxxxxxx-P");
               $xml->writeElement("Nombre", "Alumno nombre 1");
               $xml->writeElement("genero", "Masculino");
            $xml->endElement(); //fin alumno
                        
            $xml->startElement("alumno"); //elemento alumno
               $xml->writeAttribute('dni', "xxxxxxxx-S");
               $xml->writeElement("Nombre", "Alumna nombre 1");
               $xml->writeElement("genero", "Femenino");
            $xml->endElement(); //fin alumno                    
         $xml->endElement(); //fin clase
                    
         $xml->startElement("clase"); //elemento responsable
            $xml->writeAttribute('id', "Clase B");
            $xml->startElement("alumno"); //elemento alumno
               $xml->writeAttribute('dni', "xxxxxxxx-Z");
               $xml->writeElement("Nombre", "Alumno nombre 3");
               $xml->writeElement("genero", "Masculino");
            $xml->endElement(); //fin alumno
         $xml->endElement(); //fin clase
      $xml->endElement(); //fin elemento alumnos
   $xml->endElement(); //fin curso
$xml->endElement(); //fin colegio

$content = $xml->outputMemory();
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=ejemplo.xml");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: cache');
header('Cache-Control: private');
echo $content;
```

Pero siempre me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Estoy probando inicialmente hacerlo sin la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando espacios en blanco para nombrar un elemento, aquí:

```
  $xml->writeElement("profesores de refuerzo", 1);
```

Eso no es permitido, [según la especificación para documentos XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Si lo cambias por algo como esto debería funcionar:

```
  $xml->writeElement("profesores_de_refuerzo", 1);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero ya reemplazo los datos donde había espacios en blanco y aún persiste el problema.

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea hice una prueba con tu código completo y el XML de generó sin problema y ningún error en el log de errores. ¿Qué error sale ahora? ¿Cómo pusiste el atributo?